# Unable to debug c++ program with class implementation

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup debugging environment in visual studio and I hope I was successful in doing it,because when I am trying to debug a normal math c++ program then my break point is hitting(or first line of code as default breakpoint) but when I am trying to debug the main program with class header file name included in the main program(i.e with class object or class implementation) then my breakpoint are not hitting. Any help where I am going wrong??

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 cout<<"hello";
 Sales_item item1, item2;
 cin >> item1 >> item2; // read a pair of transactions
 cout << item1 + item2 << endl; // print their sum
 return 0;
}
```

This is showing in cppdgb console:

> C:\Users\admin\Documents\cpp>c:\Users\admin.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-0.26.1\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe
>   --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-w2a4a5fw.4hb --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-q2oc4jsv.b14 --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-rlvf2qhl.2bw --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-3fayxkbu.ji4 --dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe --interpreter=mi

Comment: Where do you set the breakpoint? Are you sure it's on a line actually used by the compiler in the generated code? Maybe that line is optimized away?

Comment: for example I tried placing breakpoint on cout<<"hello" ; and the line of cin also.but above message shows in terminal and nothing happens but debugger will be in processing